# Mongoose with TypesScript slows down VSCode code completion

Tags: typescript, mongoose, visual-studio-code

I have seen that Mongoose supports TS. I have followed their official getting started guide: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/typescript.html
And since then, my code completion are very slow - unless I remove this package.

Answer (score 0):

Credit: https://github.com/Thisura98

I had the same issue and it seems it is a known problem with mongoose 5.

This answer helped me to solve it for now. Maybe it will help you too:
https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10349#issuecomment-885741850

In short:

```
npm i mongoose@5.10.19 --save
npm i @types/mongoose@5.10.5 --save
```